# Как спарсить сайт без api в android приложение, если сайт без API?

Tags: android, парсер, api, jsoup, веб-сайт

Нужно спарсить данные с веб сайта в android приложение (используя jsop), **НО** данные находятся в личном аккаунте сайта, и у сайта к тому же нет api. Как спарсить данные с личного кабинета, аккаунта с сайта, если к тому же у него нет api, в приложение android (java)?
Перечислю проблемы задачи:

1. Нужно, чтобы приложение (код java) авторизовалось, зашло на аккаунт.
2. Нужно спарсить данные с сайта, не имеющий видимого api.
3. Как то использовать jsop для парсинга в android приложения.

Comment: ну, то что вы задачи сформировали это безусловно хорошо, но не могли бы вы пожалуйста уточнить с чем именно у вас возникли проблемы, приложите код к вопросу, добавьте деталей

Answer (score 1):

1. Авторизованный запрос от неавторизованного отличается наличием пароля в запросе. Это может быть токен в параметре запроса или кука в заголовке.
2. Получить куку или токен можно путём отправки запроса на авторизацию. В ответ сервер пришлёт нужные данные.
3. Выяснять как происходит авторизация для получения пароля и как этот пароль использовать надо путём просмотра запросов соответствующих в консоли браузера. После этого эти запросы просто надо повторить программно.